# Why didn't Dumbledore use magic to figure out what Bertie Bott’s Every Flavor Beans taste like?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

At the end of the first book:

> [...] Ah! Bertie Bott’s Every Flavor Beans! I was unfortunate enough
>   in my youth to come across a vomit-flavored one, and since then I’m
>   afraid I’ve rather lost my liking for them — but I think I’ll be safe
>   with a nice toffee, don’t you?” He smiled and popped the golden-brown
>   bean into his mouth. Then he choked and said, “Alas! Ear wax!

Can't the most powerful wizard in the world just do magic to find the taste so that he doesn't tastes anything that he may not like?

Comment: What fun would that be?

Comment: the same reason people don't look at the guide on boxes of assorted chocolates.

Comment: I think he was busy with more important things. FWIW, there is no canon answer to this question.

Comment: @phantom42 Why would you not look at the guide? Got to grab the best ones before somebody else does!

Comment: Also, Dumbledore does quite enjoy his jokes. There's no guarantee it was actually ear wax flavour. (Please nobody ask that as a question...)

Comment: Why didn't XX use magic to YY? This can be asked about almost  anything that didn't happen in Harry Potter

Comment: I think we've just struck on a fundamental human dichotomy here - the people who just take whatever chocolate the box gives them, and the kind who need the guide...

Comment: For all we know they're enchanted to stop that sort of thing, as it would, as others have pointed out, ruin the fun.

Comment: @phantom42 - they don't? I do. I always guessed everyone does

Comment: Life is like a box of Bertie Bott’s Every Flavor Beans....

Comment: @DVK - I am not a smart man.

Comment: @phantom42: What? That sounds very dangerous!  Many people are allergic to nuts or white flour or milk or other ingredients, and some of these allergies can cause very serious medical emergencies.  Awareness to this seems to have started only in the last decade, at least in this part of the world, so I'm not surprised if Wizards in the Potterverse don't care, but do people do that in real life?

Comment: @b_jonas believe it or not, there are people without any major food allergies.

Comment: @phantom42: According to some viewpoints, yes.  According to others, we just don't have our allergies diagnosed yet, so we don't know what specifically we should avoid.  But sure, some people don't need to read the labels.

Comment: @b_jonas you must be fun at parties. Take a chance in your life, be adventurous, eat an assorted chocolate without reading the label... YOLO.

Comment: An alternate possibility is that Professor Dumbledore simply lied, just like he did about the socks.  Maybe he could tell which bean is of what taste and deliberately picked the worst tasting one he could find for dramatic effect, or didn't care about the tastes and lied about the bean being earwax.

Answer (score 3):

According to [JKR](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1101-bbcbristol-ballard.htm), the whole point of Bertie Bott's beans is that they're ***hilarious***. You literally never know what you're going to get; something wonderful, something mundane or something genuinely disgusting.

> **JKR:** *Bertie Bott’s Every Flavour Beans are beans that literally do comprise every flavour, so that you have liver... tripe, marmalade,
>   erm, chocolate... vomit is mentioned, earwax is mentioned... that
>   would be hysterical if they did that, I’d love it. [laughs]*

If you were to cheat and use magic to identify the flavour in advance (assuming such a thing was possible, these are *magic* beans after all), that would remove some of the amusement.

You might just as well ask why students don't enchant their [fever fudge](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fever_Fudge) not to cause a fever

Comment: I think they must be enchanted so the user recognizes flavor on tasting. How would Dumbledore know they taste like ear wax? Has he tasted ear wax before and remembered it?

Comment: @zikato - He's a old man. I dare say he's tasted earwax at least once in his long life, if only to satisfy his curiosity

Comment: and it was such an experience that he remembered the flavour his whole life.

Comment: @zikato - For a dare, I once licked a burnt car tyre. Suffice to say, 25 years later the memory has not left me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, finding out the flavor of the beans would require divination.  Professor Dumbledore was a very powerful wizard, but I believe he **wasn't very good in divination**.  He admits himself in *Half-Blood Prince* chapter 20:

> […] ‘Divination is turning out to be much more trouble than I could have foreseen, never having studied the subject myself. […]‘

And also in *Prisoner of Azkaban* chapter 22.

> ‘[…] The consequences of our actions are always so complicated, so diverse, that predicting the future is a very difficult business indeed … Professor Trelawney, bless her, is living proof of that. […]’

Professor Dumbledore used his great people skills, mind-altering magic, and network of spies to find out a lot of information about the past history and future plans of the Dark Lord, but it doesn't seem like he's ever used divination for that.

(Update: on second thought, it's hard to be sure, because Hermione, who has quit Divination lessons early, has still cast at least one Divination spell in *Hallows*.)

Professor Dumbledore may have had friends in the Order or Hogwarts who could have helped him in divination magic, and it would have been even in character for him to ask them a favor for finding out the flavor of some every-flavored beans, but he chose not to do that for some reason.

Secondly some magic systems have ways to explicitly **block divination**.  These certainly exist already in the Harry Potter universe too, because the Order of the Phoenix could successfully protect its secrets from even the Dark Lord, who is a very powerful wizard and also had powerful allies.  The Fidelius (secret keeper) charm was one method used for this, but I believe there were others, including possibly house elf magic.

Case in point, Hermione has cast some divination blocking spells when they were on the run.  This is revealed clearly in *Deathly Hallows* chapter 19.

> ‘One thing I would like to know, though,’ she [Hermione] said, fixing her eyes on a spot a foot over Ron's head. ‘How exactly did you find us tonight? That's important. Once we know, we'll be able to make sure we're not visited by anyone else we don't want to see.’
>
> […]
>
> ‘Yeah, well, that would've been me,’ said Ron. ‘Your protective spells work, anyway, because I couldn't see you and I couldn't hear you. I was sure you were around, though, so in the end I got in my sleeping bag and waited for one of you to appear. I thought you'd have to show yourselves when you packed up the tent.’

Thirdly, let me point to a very similar example, from later than *Philosopher's Stone*, of divination failing in such a frivolous way.  In [*The Order of the Stick* strip #413](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0413.html), Haley points out in panel 13 that the royal court of Azure City could not buy booster packs that contain the right pre-painted minifigures, despite that they have a very good sage.  This is probably common in the Order of the Stick universe, because [there are shops making a business from selling spells in randomized booster packs](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0049.html) to wizards, many of whom are likely good diviners.

---

Update: I added the quote from *Prince* chapter 20, removed a less relevant quote, and reorganized the text around them a little.  Thanks to [TenthJustice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/30859/tenthjustice) for pointing out this quote in [Why did Dumbledore contemplate discontinuing Divination at Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67483/4918) and to Slytherincess for locating the quote.

Comment: Divination is seeing into the future.  Finding out what flavour a particular bean is doesn't have anything to do with the future.

Comment: Agreed, downvoted since the basic premise of the answer is flawed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I tend to disagree, if you look a few seconds into the future you would know what the bean would taste like...

Comment: @Thomas: sure, that would be *one* way to do it.  But not the only one.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I don't think divination is only about predicting the future.  It's about finding out hidden information in general.  For example, see the description of the divination school of wizard spells in Dungeons and Dragons at http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#divination : "Divination spells enable you to learn secrets long forgotten, to predict the future, to find hidden things, and to foil deceptive spells."  (The Isaac Asimov short story *The Dead Past* is slightly relevant.)

Comment: That said, I hope at least part of my answer is still relevant even if you use a different definition of "divination".

Comment: Oh! A comment for http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/67483/4918 claims *Prince* has a definite quote where Dumbledore says he's never studied Divination.  I'll look this up in the book later and update my answer.

Comment: The point is, what other authors/universes states about divination is irrelevant in Harry Potter. In HP, divination == seeing the future/making prophecies (as long as the canon is concerned).

Comment: @AlfredoHernández: I don't think so, though it's hard to tell.  We've only seen lessons from two Hogwarts teachers, one of who couldn't teach too well, and one who didn't represent the viewpoint of Wizards.  If you only knew of Defense agains the Dark Arts from Professor Quirrel and Lockhart, you could have a skewed view of that area as well.  What divination covers in the HP universe may be an interesting question that maybe I should ask on this site though.

Comment: @b_jonas absolutely. That would be a brilliant question!

Comment: @AlfredoHernández: now asked as http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95287/4918

Comment: Hermione's protective spells were not divination blocking! Think of them as a giant invisibility cloak that blocks sound.