# Had Professor Trelawney ever predicted something that turned out to be true?

Tags: harry-potter, divination

Because she always talked rubbish about omens, deaths, the Grim, etc, which never happened. Even Professor McGonagall told students not to pay attention to her nonsense. I also wonder why Dumbledore kept her as a teacher.

Comment: ...yes? And it is a major plot point!!

Comment: Just for clarity, have you finished all the books?

Comment: not yet, I'm reading now HP and the prisoner of Azkaban

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Answer quick, easy rep

Comment: @Edlothiad the only reason I would like to have more rep is to vote to close questions like this one

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 Possibly another major plot point as well (13 seated at the table). And many minor.

Comment: The linked question answers your question as well, but I would advise __against reading anything on this topic__, because it's all spoilers and all. Also related: [Is Sybill Trelawney taken lightly more often than necessary?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/120393/70236)