# Can you actually *learn* Divination through studying?

Tags: harry-potter, divination

In the world of Harry Potter, it appears that Divination is a mostly hereditary field; the only seers shown in the books are all related. Students studying the field in class, however, appear to have limited luck -- they try to see the future in leaves and cards, but most seem to go nowhere.

Firenze describes the human version of Divination as

> Self-flattering nonsense

The centaurs, however, use a form of Divination that is much closer to Astrology.  That form, too, appears to have limited success.

Trelawney herself says

> Many witches and wizards, talented though they are in the area of loud bangs and smells and sudden disappearings, are yet unable to penetrate the veiled mysteries of the future.

So the question remains: Can a student succeed at Divination via sheer hard work?

[image: Divination not working]

Comment: Maybe, but as Harry and Ron know, studying is totally not worth it

Comment: I think yes, but you have to have the natural potential. Some would never be good at it, some are ok at it and might learn something and a few are gifted but need training up.

Comment: I wonder if the size of the prophesy room at the ministry tells us anything.

Comment: Doesn't the top answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67481/why-did-dumbledore-contemplate-discontinuing-divination-at-hogwarts) answer this question?

Comment: @randal'thor It does. At least this "dupe" would actually be a dupe.

Comment: @Axelrod Closed as dupe, with your kind permission :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what the wiki says:

> Non-Seers can learn divination methods, but their success varies

For once, I totally agree with the wiki, and my reasoning is very simple: Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry has been teaching their third years and up Divination for over a thousand years.  Through all of those years, a lot of different smart people (and Dolores Umbridge) have been part of the school's administration.  Many of these people are responsible for groundbreaking discoveries in all fields of magic (on the other hand, Umbridge) so it is ***highly*** unlikely that the fact that Divination can't be taught has gone unnoticed for so long.  It is true that it is hard to learn it--almost impossible, in fact, but it is possible.  Even for extremely Gifted Seers, who are in touch with their Inner Eyes or whatever cannot See very much, so it stands to reason that there won't be many learned Seers and that they will mostly get their predictions wrong (not as much, of course, as Dolores Umbridge, who got a Troll on her O.W.L).

Comment: I must not tell lies: I am not a fan of Umbridge.

Comment: it may be because she behaved like a **troll**.... also ***Dumbledore*** thought the whole subject to be unnecessary... And Dumbledore's thinking normally turns out to be accurate....

Answer (score 3):

It is more like a natural instinct or talent (for non-seers). Some tend to have a knack for it, and some don't. And in humans, those some and how they had that talent is unclear in the books.

For example, where Professor Trelawney has been seeing all sorts of signs like the grim and what not; Harry and Ron couldn't even see **anything,** except for a waft of clouds.

So, it is more of a natural instinct which can be nurtured through relevant education, rather than something like Potions or Transfiguration, which can be learned from scratch and till achieving mastery.